# how to do this kind of check of a form value?

Tags: php

I need a little help with this:

a have form.php:

```
<?php
<form name="create" method="post" action="done.php">
<input type="email" name="email" class="cform" required />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>                             
?>
```

Now, in done.php I have:

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['email'];
$OtherVar = email@gmail.com;
?>
```

My question is, How to determine if "$email" is equal to "$OtherVar" but without exit form.php?

If "$email" = "$OtherVar" lets user to send the form.

If "$email" is not = "$OtherVar" show a message to user.

Hope you had understad my question and you can help me, sorry for my english and thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check the e-mail **before** submitting the form, you need to do it on client side in javascript. PHP can't be applied if you before you submit the form.

```
<form onsubmit="return checkEmail(this.email.value)" action="done.php">
    <input name="email" type="text">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
function checkEmail(email) {
    return email == 'email@gmail.com';
}
</script>
```

But you can also allow submittin with any e-mail and if the e-mail is not the one you want, return the user back to the form to fill it again.

```
if ($email != "email@gmail.com") {
    header('Location: form.php');
}
```

Please note that if you'd be using javascript, the required e-mail address is by no means secret: anyone can find it in the source code of the page. On the other hand the PHP solution with returning back to the form hides the e-mail address from a random visitor (while I still don't recommend to think of it as of a security layer in any way).

Comment: Great! I did it with the second way! I add it a few things and it works :) thanks you and thanks everybody else.

Answer (score 1):

Include jquery

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Give your form and your email field an id so you can call it by jquery:

```
<?php
<form name="create" id="create" method="post" action="done.php">
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="cform" required />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>                             
?>
```

Now call it by jquery and check if the values are the same. if they are not, you are using the `preventDefault()` method, which stops the form from submitting:

```
$('#create').submit(function(event) {

var email = $('#email').val();
var otherVariable = 'someValue;

if(!(email == otherVariable)) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it inside `form.php` without JavaScript is by having `form.php` handle the post action:

```
<?php if ($_POST && $_POST['email'] == $OtherVar) { ?>
    // User submitted desired email address
<?php } else { ?>
    // User didn't submit desired email address
    <form name="create" method="post" action="form.php">
        <input type="email" name="email" class="cform" required />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
<?php } ?>
```

That'd have a page refresh though. If you want it done without a page refresh, you'd need to use some JavaScript or jQuery:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<form name="create" method="post" action="done.php">
    <input id="special-input" type="email" name="email" class="cform" required />
    <input id="special-submit" type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#special-submit').click(function () {
        if ($('#special-input').val() != "<?php echo $OtherVar; ?>") {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
</script>
```